# old values appearing in chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Im working with chart.js and am having an issue filtering results. My wep page has several sub pages that are just filtered versions of the main page. When a filter is triggered the charts values change. When a filtered page has no values it is returning the main pages totals, It also seems to be not refreshing. On the main page a value appears that should be there, but on each filtered page, that value still appears, even though a var_dump says its not called. Is there a way to refresh or redraw?

```
<script>
                var compareConfig = {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: {
              labels: [<?php
                  $lMonth = 0;
                  foreach ($lastYrData as $lastMo){
                    if ($lMonth < 11){
                      echo '"'.$lastMo['month'].'",';
                    }else{
                      echo '"'.$lastMo['month'].'"';
                    }
                    ++$lMonth;
                  }
                  echo '],'."\n";
                ?>
                        datasets: [{
                            label: "<?php echo date('Y', strtotime("-1 year", time()));?>",
                            fill: true,

                            borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
                            data: [
                    <?php
                      $lTotal = 0;
                      foreach ($lastYrData as $lastYrs){
                        if ($lTotal < 11){
                          echo '"'.$lastYrs['total'].'",';
                        }else{
                          echo '"'.$lastYrs['total'].'"';
                        }
                        ++$lTotal;
                      }
                    ?>],
                        }, {
                            label: "<?php echo date('Y', time());?>",

                            borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                            data: [
                    <?php
                      $tTotal = 0;
                      foreach ($thisYrData as $thisYr){
                        if ($tTotal < 11){
                          echo $thisYr['total'].',';
                        }else{
                          echo $thisYr['total'];
                        }
                        ++$tTotal;
                      }
                    ?>
                            ],
                            fill: true,
                        }]
                    },
                    options: {

                        responsive: true,
                        title:{
                            display:false,
                            text:''
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            mode: 'index',
                            intersect: false,
                        },

                        hover: {
                            mode: 'nearest',
                            intersect: true
                        },
                        scales: {
                            xAxes: [{
                                display: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: 'Month'
                                }
                            }],
                            yAxes: [{
                              ticks: {
                               beginAtZero: true,
                               userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                                   value = value.toString();
                                   value = value.split(/(?=(?:...)*$)/);

                                   value = value.join('.');
                                   return '$' + value;
                                   }
                                },
                                display: true,
                                scaleLabel: {
                                    display: false,
                                    labelString: '$ Totals',


                                }

                            }]
                        }

                    }
                };
    </script>
```